# Cómo unir multiples filas que contienen un dato en común?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes, por favor, necesito agrupar los valores del campo buscador en una sola fila que corresponde al mismo valor del campo codigo.

Es decir, por ejemplo tengo el código 1080  y a este código le corresponde los campos sos_loja(00),sos_cuenca(00),sos_quito(00), sos_ambato(00) pero estos campos se encuentran en filas separadas aunque se sabe que pertenecen al código 1080

Utilizo ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER 21.2.1.204 , entonces necesito su ayuda en que me queda la tabla de la siguiente forma por favor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas queda mejor porque no se asume que estás gritando. Por favor ve a [edit] tu pregunta, indica qué versión de SQL Server usas y cómo intentaste agrupar los datos

Comment: ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER 21.2.1.204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen diferentes manera de hacerlo según la versión de Oracle que uses por ejemplo el `LISTAGG` o el `XMLAGG` que ambos casos te puede ayudar en tu problema ya depende de ti cual usar según tu criterio.

Te dejo este [enlace](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) donde viene toda la información sobre lo que necesitas con explicaciones y diferentes maneras de hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo conseguí gracias al LISTAGG, muchas gracias!